# Handling HTML character encoding issues

Tags: html, encoding, iconv, phpquery

*-Think this is called character encoding but please re-title if I'm wrong-*

**Issue:** Trying to consume HTML with phpquery and maintain the html's integrity after it runs through the phpquery functions.

These are the changes to the HTML as it runs through the functions:

1. **Original HTML:** `<strong> Fast & Strong I Concrete</strong>`
2. **HTML Page Converted to PHPQueryObject:** `<strong> Fast& Strong I&Acirc;&nbsp;Concrete</strong>`
3. **PHPQueryObject run through Find() function:** `<strong> Fast & Strong IÂ Concrete</strong>`

Tried various combinations of `htmlentities()`, `html_entity_decode()`, `iconv()` to handle the movement of the data and maintain the original structure without displaying a bunch of unnecessary characters. I think this is a limitation of phpquery’s ability to consume html, so I need a work around.

I’ve been successful removing the Â and other unneeded characters by using `iconv("UTF-8", "BIG5//IGNORE")` but it is somewhat destructive to the original html since it’s intended for Traditional Chinese Characters.

**Question:** What are `&Acirc;` and `&nbsp;` and how can I handle them so the consumed html #2 and #3 above display as originally intended #1 above without displaying extra characters to the browser?

Comment: Are you able to use `htmlentities()` on the HTML first, before you use the `PHPQueryObject`?

Comment: @Jason Gennaro - I might be able to do that. The PHPQueryObject is the means for finding the html, so it's sort of a catch 22 trying to perform a function on the html before I've found it.

Comment: what encoding do you use in your php, and html?

Comment: @Gerben - Using ISO-8859-1, but the server is reporting UTF-8 in the Header.

Comment: Try using utf8 for everything. I think PHPQueryObject assumes the content is utf8.

Comment: @Gerben - I think you're right about enconding assumptions. Now using iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $string) on the original html, and each time the html moves through a phpquery function and so far no unneeded characters are appearing. This converts from UTF-8 back to the original encoding of the html.

Comment: I had tried converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 after the phpQuery functions previously, but adding the conversion to the original html and after the phpquery functions proved to be the difference.